# Building a single binary `cargo build --bin my_single_bin` does not work

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How can I build a single binary with Rust Cargo?

According to the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html), this should build only a single binary:

`cargo build --bin my_single_binary`

But it builds all of my code unfortunately.

So what am I missing?

My folder structure is like this:

```
~/project/bin/my_single_binary
~/project/src
```

And Cargo.toml has this:

```
[[bin]]
name = "my_single_binary"
path = "bin/my_single_binary.rs"
```

Comment: It doesn't fail; it builds ALL of my code every time. I have ten binaries -- it builds all of them, not one.

Comment: I haven't observed this behavior(cargo/rustc 1.73.0),  have you cleaned previous builds? Which version of  cargo you are using?

Comment: cargo 1.71.0-nightly (ac8401032 2023-05-02) just upgraded to 1.75 and cargo cleaned. Still builds everything.

Comment: Could you share the exact Cargo output?

Comment: OT: independent of the problem I'd recommend putting binaries in `project/src/bin` that way they're detected by `cargo` without the need for any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm sorry for my bad english, I'm french and I do with my knowledges.

Can you send the entire content of all your `config.toml` files or others generated from Rust. Do you use workspaces ?

To run only one binary from a Cargo workspace, you need to specify the name of the package and not of the binary.

E.g:

```ini
[package]
name = "my_amazing_project"

[[bin]]
name = "foo"
```

You need to do `cargo run --bin my_amazing_project` and not `foo` (I think, I'm not sure).

Have a nice day !